# Where can I find Solution Navigator after installing Productivity Power Tools 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, productivity-power-tools

I'm really interest in using solution navigator after reading the article about
[Productivity Power Tools 2012.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

After I install Productivity Power Tools 2012 in my VS2012, somehow I can't find the solution navigator everywhere. Could someone tell me where can I find it? Also in the article didn't mention it.

By the way, I couldn't find it in "View" and Quick Launch...

It will be really helpful to me and lot of peoples if someone suggests the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution Navigator was a part of Productivity Power Tools for VS 2010. In VS 2012 many features of Solution Navigator were integrated in the standard Solution Explorer and PPT 2012 don't include the separate Solution Navigator tool any more.

Comment: But I can't find many function in VS2012 Solution Explorer, for example:
"Filter your solution or projects to see just opened files, unsaved files, and so on" , "View related information about classes and members (such as references or callers/callees for C#)" , Is it possible to do it the same?

Comment: @AndyChen "Open Files Filter" is available from a drop-down button in the Solution Explorer toolbar. Looks like other features you ask were not transferred to VS 2012.