# How to display a "member list" tooltip in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tooltip, editor, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2010, I frequently used a text editor feature (C#) that would show the members of a class in a pop-up list box when the mouse cursor was hovered over a variable or a class name. I have been unable to find that option in Visual Studio 2015. I thought Quick Info was it, but I have it enabled and all VS2015 does now is show the class declaration and summary description without detail.

Did Microsoft remove this feature or hide it somewhere else? I'd desperately like to get it back. The "Peek" preview operations don't work for me because they show the entire source module, making it too cluttered to use. A VS extension to restore this feature would be acceptable, if one were available, but Power Tools doesn't have it.

Would somebody please tell me how I can get this functionality in VS2015.

**Update:** This feature came from a VS extension: *Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010*. There was an option named *Solution Navigator* that had a function for *Interactive tooltip*. When enabled and the mouse hovered over a class, the extension displayed a tooltip with summary documentation, like VS, but added a drop-down list. The list showed all members of the class. It also allowed navigation through all namespaces and classes, starting with the one the mouse cursor was over, so you could browse related classes, too.

Depressingly, the Productivity Power Tools extension for VS2015 (and VS2013) did away with those features.

If there is another extension that adds these features, I would love to know about it.

Comment: Are you talking about UML? http://www.infoworld.com/article/3131600/application-development/uml-to-be-ejected-from-microsoft-visual-studio.html

Comment: No. I am not talking about a designer; just an Intellisense feature that used to show a list of class members as a tooltip when the mouse cursor was over a class name or variable while editing code. It may have even required a right-click, but it's been a couple years since it was available to me.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+SPACE when the cursor is on a type?

Comment: @Suncat2000, The ‘Quick Info’ still works in VS 2015, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and I compared the quick info of one class and the result is https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgmOwj_I6OfA5aivA. Go to Tools-Options-Text Editor—All Languages or C#, make sure “Auto list members” and ‘Parameter information’ is checked. If not, please checked them and save. If it is already checked, uncheck them and save, then check them again and save, create a new C# project to test. You can also try to create other project template like VB to test it.

Comment: @itsme86 CTRL+SPACE goes back to the text cursor to edit code, which adds a great deal of agitation when I'm trying to browse the other end of a 2000-line file.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Thanks. I found out that Quick Info wasn't what I was looking for. It was the Solution Explorer interactive tooltip feature from Production Power Tools 2010 I wanted, as described in my update.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reminder and I found the interactive tooltips in C# and VB code that you said, the 'Solution Navigator' already moved from Productivity Power Tools from version 2012, please check this related thread: [Where can I find Solution Navigator after installing Productivity Power Tools 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417271/where-can-i-find-solution-navigator-after-installing-productivity-power-tools-20) and the interactive tooltip also removed from version 2015.

When I hover the class name and right click it, there is an option 'Peek Help' as below that can provide the same information just like the interactive tooltip.
[image]

If you still want the interactive tooltip in VS 2015, you can also report this user voice to the VS product team: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide and share the link in here, if other community members who have the same idea can vote it.

Comment: Thanks, Sara. The Peek Help is basically a source code view and much too verbose for my use. I want a simple member list. The Microsoft team members in charge of the Productivity Power Tools were soliciting comments and I answered; they seemed happy to get the feedback and interested in restoring this lost functionality.

Comment: Have you already reported this idea to the VS Product Team? If so, could you please share the link, I have checked this Productivity Power Tools in VS 2017, it looks like this interactive tooltip have not be added yet. If not, I can help you to post it and please feel free to let me know :)